# Are btrfs updates rolled in to 12.04 LTS (3.2) kernels?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, filesystem, btrfs

Many BTRFS bug fixes and updates are being applied to the 3.10 Kernel by the filesystem maintainers - is Ubuntu actively pushing those fixes and updates down to their current LTS kernel (3.2.0-X)?

Specifically, if I convert to BTRFS for my server infrastructure using Precise, am I going to inherit all the BTRFS bugs present in the 3.2 kernel, or are bug fixes and features being put inline with each "linux-image-3.2.0-X" kernel update?

Cheers,
Kyle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Ubuntu only adds new hardware support to older kernels and backports security fixes or severe regular bugs.

Since 12.04 LTS this process enhanced by including completely newer kernels from later Ubuntu releases. This means you can install the Quantal and Raring kernel in 12.04 straight from the repositories. Just wait for a few months and you'll find the Ubuntu 13.10 kernel in 12.04.

Please note that this won't backport userspace binaries for Btrfs support! So be aware about using the Btrfs tools from the 12.04 repositories on a newer kernel.

See also: [Ubuntu wiki: LTS Hardware Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).

[image]